# The virtual keyboard pushing the bottom element up in html

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, html

I have a bottom table which lies at the bottom of the webpage bottom:30px, but when I try to tap on the input boxes to provide an input the bottom table rises up along with the keyboard pops upside.

CSS code:

```
.progress-table {
height: 1px; 
width: 100%; 
border:1px;
position:absolute !important;
bottom: 30px;
```

}

HTML Code

```
<table class="progress-table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 60%;"><hr style="border: 2px solid #ffb414; margin-left:15px; margin-top:0px;" align="left" width="100%" /></td>

        <td style="width:93%"> <div class="hr" style="padding-bottom:19.9px"></div>  </td>

        <td style="width: 50%; align-content:center;">
            <img src="/lib/ZSLogo.png" style="width:25px; height:12px; margin-right:15px;margin-bottom:19.9px" />
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[When the keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMJcq.jpg)

you may notice how the bar is above the text input area.

I want it to be lying where it was before the keyboard pops.
the prior image is here:[Here is the image for the normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpKzB.png)

In short, the orange bar should not push upwards with the appearance of the keyboard.

Comment: That's because your screen size decrease when the keyboard pop-up. So your code "is correct" because your progress-bar is still at 30px from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, @Djamel, yes i know but how to fix the issue? :)

Comment: You should first get ride of the absolute position and of the bottom 30px too

Comment: Can you edit to add your html code of this ?

Comment: Djamel I have added the HTML code. Please have a look.